# Can a cheater vent be installed in a vanity drain that maybe running into a roof vented drain?

Tags: plumbing, vent

Can a "cheater vent" be installed in a vanity drain that MAY be running into a roof vented drain? All p-trap , tail piece is new and drain line has been cleaned with a drum auger netting no major blockage. Vacuum does appear to be issue. Will drain, only very slowly with gurgling /burping.

Comment: By _cheater vent_, you are referring to an air admittance valve, correct?

Comment: Search this site fir air admittance valve lots of info about them